# How to use Jquery validation on the radio button with respected fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

My issue is regarding jquery validation. I have a form and validation is working on input field but I am confused how to use the validation on the radio button because  I have three radio buttons and the user can choose only one. All the radio button have their respected fields. I have to set the validation on it.

Example: I choose the first radio then the user should enter the book1 and book2 fields as well. If you choose the second radio then the user should enter the fruit1 and fruit2 fields value.

if user choose only radio button and without filling the fields details and clicked on submit then validation should display.

I tried some code. It's working for first radio button but what if any user chooses a second radio button?

**This is the output I am getting.**

[image]

**Radio button Book is checked with Jquery validation if fields are empty**

[image]

**Notice here I choose fruit and clicked on submit button but validation is not displaying**

[image]

The reason was I am not getting because I added only book radio button validation. Now how to use for fruit and subject?

```
book1: {required: true},
book2: {required: true}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='books_fruit_sub']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $(".show_fields").hide();
    $("#show" + test).show();
  });


  $('#form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
      mobile: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10
      },
      book1: {
        required: true
      },
      book2: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
      form.submit();

    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="books_fruit_sub" id="books" value="books" checked>
      <label for="books">Books</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="books_fruit_sub" id="fruit" value="fruit">
      <label for="fruit">Fruit </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="books_fruit_sub" id="subject" value="subject">
      <label for="subject">Subject </label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <div class="show_fields" id="showbooks">
      <input type="text" name="book1" placeholder="Book 1">
      <input type="text" name="book2" placeholder="Book 2">
    </div>

    <div class="show_fields" id="showfruit" style="display: none;">
      <input type="text" name="fruit1" placeholder="Fruit 1">
      <input type="text" name="fruit2" placeholder="Fruit 2">
    </div>

    <div class="show_fields" id="showsubject" style="display: none;">
      <input type="text" name="subject1" placeholder="Subject 1">
      <input type="text" name="subject2" placeholder="Subject 2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Comment: change $('#form').validate when you select radio button?

Comment: @ChrisLi, for example, The user choose books radio then input field book1 and book2 will appear. I have to set validation on it. If the user chooses fruit the input fields appear. but the user can choose only on the radio button.

Comment: change validation rule based on which radio button you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a function that return true or false depending on if the related radio buttton is selected or not.

```
book1: {
    required: function() {
        return $('#books').is(':checked');
    }
},
book2: {
    required: function() {
        return $('#books').is(':checked');
   }
}, 
fruit1: {
    required: function() {
        return $('#fruit').is(':checked');
    }
},
fruit2: {
    required: function() {
        return $('#fruit').is(':checked');
    }
},
..
```

To be consequent use the plural form `"fruits"` and `"subjects"` as you did for `"books"` for your radio-buttons.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvUZOtYDJe60hBWcElIk) is your modified and working code in plunker.

Comment: I have to use your code in jquery validation. Right?

Comment: It will be good for me if you share the whole code because I tried your code but it's not working for me.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a link to my Plunker with your modified and working code.

Comment: Yes, Your plunker link is working perfectly for me. Give me some time to implement your code with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that. Using ES20xx, data-attributes and css it's fairly easy to create your own form validation. Let's, just for fun, work out an example based on your code.

- We need a function to determine the chosen value of a radio button, that's `checkRadio` in the snippet;
- We need a function to show or hide fields belonging to a radio button choice,    that's `switchFieldsBasedOnRadioChoice` in the snippet. That function is activated by `clickHandling`. We use the chosen value from `checkRadio` to identify `div#show[chosen value]]` to be able to show the right div containing the input elements belonging to the chosen value;
- We need an Object containing some methods to check fields denoted in html by `data-check` and activated by the value of `[data-check]`, it's called `fieldChecks`;
- We need a handler function for the (submit) button which will check all fields denoted by `[data-check]` for field value validity and warn if the field value is not valid, that's `checkValues`, activated by `clickHandling`;
- We also create a `focusin`-handler that removes warnings from a previous input values check if the user clicks on or focuses one of the form fields;
- We use data-attributes and css to style and display the warning values. Every text-input is wrapped in a `div`. We use the css class `.invalid` for (input fields container)-`div` that to style the warnings on the containing input fields (if applicable).
- *Notes*

  - the handlers (`click`, `focusin`) in this snippet use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).
  - client side validation is *never* sufficient. You should *always* check the fields values server side too before handling them at the server.

[see also](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/mruyzafv/embedded/result,js,html,css)

```js
// check value of a radio button
const checkRadio = name => {
  const isChecked = 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[name='${name}']`))
      .filter(rb => rb.checked);
    return isChecked.length ? isChecked[0].value : null;
};
// validity checks for field values ([data-check])
const fieldChecks = {
  mobile: value => { 
    const valueClean = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    return {
      cando: valueClean.length === 10,
      instruction: "Invalid: need 10 digits, you can use spaces and '-'"
    };
  },
  booksOrFruits: value => ({
    cando: value.trim().length >= 5,
    instruction: "Invalid: all fields ≥ 5 characters"
  }),
};

// add event listeners
document.addEventListener("click", clickHandling);
document.addEventListener("focusin", removeWarnings);

// click handling delegate
function clickHandling(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.type === "radio") {
    return switchFieldsBasedOnRadioChoice(origin);
  } else if (origin.id === "validate") {
    return checkValues();
  }
}

// focusin handling delegate: remove warnings on focus 
function removeWarnings() {
  console.clear();
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".notvalid"))
    .forEach( el => el.classList.remove("notvalid") );
}

// check all field values  and warn for invalid values in required fields
function checkValues() {
  console.clear();
  const checks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-check]"));
  let cando = true;
  checks.forEach( input => {
      // check for existence of input.dataset.check
      if (!fieldChecks[input.dataset.check]) {
        throw new Error(
          `You forgot to add '${input.dataset.check}' to fieldChecks!`
        );
      }
      const parent = input.parentNode;
      
      // don't check input values from parent class "show_fields hidden"
      if (parent.classList.contains("show_fields") 
        && parent.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        return false;
      }
      
      // perform the check denoted by [data-check] from the input field
      const fieldChck = fieldChecks[input.dataset.check](input.value);
      
      // if invalid value, use css/data-attributes to style a warning      
      if (!fieldChck.cando) {
        parent.classList.add("notvalid");
        if (fieldChck && fieldChck.instruction) {
          parent.dataset.instruction = fieldChck.instruction;
        }
        cando = false;
      } else {
        parent.classList.add("valid")
      }
    } );
   // all fields checked out ok 
   if (cando) { console.log("you're ok"); }
}

// show input fields belonging to a chosen radio input field
function switchFieldsBasedOnRadioChoice(origin) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".show_fields"))
      .forEach(v => v.classList.add("hidden"))
  const chosenValue = checkRadio(origin.name);
  document.querySelector(`#show${chosenValue}`)
     .classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2em;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
input[type=text] {
  margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
button {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
/* fields originating from radio choice */
.show_fields {
  display: table-row;
  visibility: "visible";
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity ease-in 0.5s 0s;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-out 0.1s 0s;
  visibility: collapse;
}
/* styling related to validation */
.notvalid input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.notvalid[data-instruction]:after {
  content: attr(data-instruction);
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}
.notvalid ::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
.valid:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "\2714";
  color: green;
}
.valid input {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="books_fruit_sub" id="books" value="books" checked>
    <label for="books">Books</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="books_fruit_sub" id="fruit" value="fruit">
    <label for="fruit">Fruit </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-required>
  <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile" data-check="mobile">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="notrequired" placeholder="not required">
</div>
<div class="show_fields" id="showbooks">
  <input type="text" name="book1" placeholder="Book 1" data-check="booksOrFruits">
  <input type="text" name="book2" placeholder="Book 2" data-check="booksOrFruits">
</div>
<div class="show_fields hidden" id="showfruit">
  <input type="text" name="fruit1" placeholder="Fruit 1" data-check="booksOrFruits">
  <input type="text" name="fruit2" placeholder="Fruit 2" data-check="booksOrFruits">
</div>

<button id="validate">Check</button>
```

Comment: @kooilnc, Thanks for the reply, I think you haven't understood my question. Should I explain in details?  In your snippet, If user choose a book radio then div will open with input fields and I have to set validation on that fields or choose fruit then div will open with input fields have to set the validation that. Please check my shipped.

Comment: Hi @NarendraVerma, I provided a minimal function to check the chosen radio input value. You can use that to show or hide the necessary fields. For your convenience, the click handler in the snippet does that now. Still no need for jQuery I'd say. Enjoy

Comment: @Kooilnc, How do I check the validation in your snippet? I think you forgot to add the submit button. Can we handle this issue using jquery validation?

Comment: @NarendraVerma worked out a more complete example for you. Ofcourse you can use jquery, but I wanted to demonstrate that it's not really necessary. Using native es20xx your scripting footprint will be (a lot) smaller

Comment: @Kooilnc, I have to do with jquery validation because I just shared the sample example. My whole form is with jquery validation.

Comment: @Kooilnc, Thanks for the help and your support. I checked your code it is also working but I don't need an advanced code. I just want simple and understandable. I will refer your code in future.  upvote from my side.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the rule for book1 and book2 from validator initialization and in your click handler just add this

`$(".show_fields").find("input").removeAttr("required");
$("#show" + test).find("input").attr("required" , "required");`

Also in html add required attribute to both inputs book1 and book2